# Mocking problems with PhpSpec and Prophecy

Tags: php, mocking, tdd, phpspec

I am trying to test a method that I have using `PhpSpec` and `Prophecy`.  I am having a little trouble getting it to work, though.  I don't want to use actual values for the mock, so I have used `Argument::any()`, but it seems to be wanting to execute the actual call inside the method.  I thought that this was what mocks were to prevent against?

My Class:

```
class CreatePostValidator
{

    protected $validator;

    protected $data;

    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required'
    ];


    public function __construct(Factory $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function with($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function passes()
    {
        $validator = $this->validator->make($this->data, $this->rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
class CreatePostValidatorSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(Factory $factory)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($factory);
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Blog\Service\Laravel\CreatePostValidator');
    }

    function it_should_return_false_if_validator_fails(
        Factory $factory, Validator $validator)
    {
        $factory->make(Argument::any(), Argument::any())->willReturn($validator);
        $validator->fails()->willReturn(true);

        $this->with(Argument::any());
        $this->passes()->shouldReturn(false);
    }
}
```

And the error I am getting back:

> error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Double\Illuminate\Validation\Factory\P2::make() must be of the type
>   array, object given, called in
>   /Users/will/development/personal/blog/app/Blog/Service/Laravel/CreatePostValidator.php
>   on line 32 and defined  in
>   /Users/will/development/personal/blog/vendor/phpspec/prophecy/src/Prophecy/Doubler/Generator/ClassCreator.php(49)
>   :
>   eval()'d code line 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is not an expectation, so just pass `[]` there:

```
$this->with([]);
```